# Do theorems involving chaotic mappings hold in a finite precision context?

Tags: error-propagation, chaos-theory

Chaotic mappings are known as highly sensitive to their initial state. It is well known that the first type of Chebyshev polynomials is chaotic, e.g. [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960184909939). This mapping is defined recursively as $T_n(x) = 2xT_{n-1}(x) - T_{n-2}(x)$, $T_0(x) = 1$ and $T_1(x) = x$. It also has a closed form of $\cos(n \times \arccos (x) )$ for $x \in [-1,+1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is also well known that $T_n(x)$ satisfies a so called semigroup property, i.e. $T_n(T_m(x)) = T_m(T_n(x))$. This property is useful in some applications in cryptography like [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00034-005-2403-x).

However, I know that in floating-point computations, e.g. IEEE 754, the numbers are rounded to their nearest representable ones. This is the place that my question arises!

How much is this chaotic mapping sensitive to a rounding error? Can we bound it? How about other chaotic mappings?

More important, is $T_n(T_m(x)) = T_m(T_n(x))$ in finite precision?

Note: I am totally new to the topic of Chaotic mappings, so even a search keyword is appreciated.

Comment: A good starting point would be the notion of _shadowing_ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowing_lemma

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki. As far as I have concluded from this Wikipedia's page on shadowing theorem, every theorem do hold for some $\epsilon > 0$ when our error is bounded by some $\delta > 0$. Am I right?